# Endpoints Issuer attribute not found.

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-oauth

I'm being told the Issuer attribute can't be found on the endpoints object.  According to google it should be there: [Authenticating Users (Frameworks)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/authenticating-users)

```
import endpoints

firebase_issuer = endpoints.Issuer(
    issuer='https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID',
    jwks_uri='https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com')

@endpoints.api(
    name='echo',
    version='v1',
    issuers=[firebase_issuer])
```

This is in my backend api which I want to allow firebase authentication.

I'm using Eclipse an the PyDev Google App engine library to write this backend.  I'm seeing the error message:

> Undefined variable from import: Issuer

or

> firebase_issuer = endpoints.Issuer(
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Issuer'

when I run it

Comment: Ok corrected, my mistake.  Hopefully this is more complete.

Comment: thanks for the formatting corrections :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. Basically, my interpreter was referencing the gcloud SDK files which only have endpoints-1.0. The quick start has you install endpoints-2.0 to a lib directory that's uploaded with deployment, but the appengine_config.py script that includes it doesn't fire until deployment (I think). I.E. it's undefined locally.

To fix, I just installed endpoints-2.0 by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`, which points at your local interpreter (mine happens to be a virtualenv). This assumes you use the requirements.txt from the repo in the quickstart: `google-endpoints==2.0.4`.

This was easiest for me, but I believe there's a way to point a virtualenv at the lib directory that the quickstart has you create and target. This way, your local interpreter would be running off the same package list that GAE would be.